# Is there a keyboard shortcut to change a element into a dialogue?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

In Final Draft, when I paste text into the editor, it defaults to an action.

If I select the text or put my cursor on a spot in the text, then I can go to the menu and choose Format > Change Element to > Dialogue. There is also a dropdown menu at the top of the editor that does this.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will let me do this?

Comment: No, according to [Final Draft 11 (Windows) keyboard shortcuts ‒ defkey](https://defkey.com/final-draft-11-windows-shortcuts)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Command + Option + 1 through 9 will reformat a paragraph to another element type. On Windows it uses the Control key.

[image]